# JavaScript. while не реагирует на setTimeout

Tags: javascript, while, settimeout

Задумка:
Реализовать код, который будет увеличивать `count` в течении секунды
Тест производительности так сказать )

Проблема:
через `while` - бесконечный цикл
через рекурсию - ошибка `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

**Через while:**

```
let running = true
let count = 0

setTimeout(() => {
    running = false
    console.log(count)
}, 1000)

while (running) {
    count++
}
```

**Через рекурсию:**

```
let running = true
let count = 0


setTimeout(() => {
  running = false
  console.log(count)
}, 1000)

function doIt(argument) {
  if (running) {
    count++
    doIt()
  }
}
```

Comment: Функция запланированная с помощью setTimeout не может начать выполняться, пока не закончилось выполнение текущей функции.

Comment: не совсем понятно что именно ты хочешь сделать/проверить?

Comment: running = true поэтому цикл бесконечный. В функции установлено false, но она даже не успевает выполнится, так как отсрочка на 1 секунду и while уходит в бесконечность. Если нужно выполнить, итерацию хоть раз, лучше переписать через "do ... while"

Comment: видимо он хочет определить, сколько инкрементов выполнится за секунду. Тест производительности делают по другому: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: Хочу понять как выполнять код в цикле в течении какого-то времени. Чтобы цикл прерывался таймером

Comment: @HaZcker Так какая цель? Если цель и заключается в том, чтобы гонять цикл одну секунду, то делайте проверку на затраченное время внутри цикла. Если цель - выяснить сколько циклов в секунду прошло, то решение обратное вашему подходу. Надо прогнать N циклов, замерив время до и после, и вычислить N/dt

Comment: @HaZcker, это невозможно, если в цикле выполняются синхронные операции

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать цикл который будет сравнивать начальное и конечное время:

```js
var count = 0;
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();

while(new Date().getTime() < timestamp+1000) {
    count++;
}

console.log(count);
```